# Basic authentication option in apache web server is not working?

Tags: apache, http, webserver, httpd.conf

I tried to configure a basic authentication for my website locally .But not applied for site .

My `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.5:80>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/black-socks
 ServerName www.black-socks.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/black-socks">
        Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName BlackSocks-LOGIN
            AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/conf/blacksocks-users"
            Require ValidUser
    </Directory>
```

```
authuserfile
```

is exist at  `/etc/httpd/conf/blacksocks-users"` and site html pages are exist at `/etc/httpd/conf/blacksocks-users`  location. everything is fine but while accessing site not asking any `authorization`

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.5:80>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/black-socks
 ServerName www.black-socks.com
     <Directory "/var/www/html/black-socks">

            Allow from ram
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName BlackSocks-LOGIN
            AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/conf/myusers"
            Require ValidUser
    </Directory>
```

Its working but asking user name and password after showing homepage